# In Polymer how do I databind data with html tags and have it displayed correctly

Tags: polymer

How do I get below to show the correctly formatted html in the div?
Thanks :-)

```
<dom-module id='my-element'>
    <template>
        <div>{{html}}</div>
    </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'my-element',

        properties: {
            html: {
                type: String,
                value: 'This is<br>a <strong>test</strong>'
            }
        }
    });
</script>
<my-element></my-element>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you wouldn't type it directly in to the `<template></template>` tag? If you're trying to inject html into the element use the `importHref()` utility function: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/utility-functions.html

Comment: The html I am getting comes from a web service and has sligh formatting in it like line feeds. So I am not sure that importHref is the right thing for the job here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding HTML like that is inadvisable as it's currently an XSS vector, however if you're determined to do so you can with this:

```
<div inner-h-t-m-l="{{html}}"></div>
```

Comment: Nice find! Is that documented anywhere? I didn't find any info on this...